# Atomicness of copy constructor of reference count object using InterlockedIncrement64

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, atomic, interlocked-increment

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can ensure that an objects reference count is thread safe.

```
class MyObject{
  //Other implementation details
private:
  mutable volatile LONGLONG * m_count;
  IData * m_data;
};
```

Assume the necessary class declaration are there, just keeping it simple.  Here is the implementation of the copy constructor and destructor.

```
MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject& rhs) : m_count(rhs.m_count), m_data(rhs.m_data){
    InterlockedIncrement64(m_count);
}

MyObject::~MyObject(){
    if(InterlockedDecrement64(m_count) == 0)
    delete m_data;
}
```

Is this thread safe?  How is the intilization list of the copy constructor seen, atomic or not?  Does that even matter?  Should I be setting the incremented value of the count in the initilization list (is this possible)?

As it stands is this good enough.  I'm thinking it is, otherwise, how could I get into a scenario where `thread1` is copying and `thread2` is destroying concurrently when the `count == 1`.  There has to be a handshake between the threads, meaning thread1 has to copy the object entirely before thread2's object goes out of scope correct?

After reading some of these responses I went back and did a little research.  Boost implements their shared_ptr very similiarly.  Here is the destructor call.

```
void release() // nothrow
{
    if( BOOST_INTERLOCKED_DECREMENT( &use_count_ ) == 0 )
    {
        dispose();
        weak_release();
    }
}
```

Some have suggested that in the boost documentation that it clearly states assignment is not thread safe.  I agree and disagree.  I think in my case I disagree.  I only need the handshake between threadA and threadB.  I don't think some of the problems described in some of the replies apply here (although they were eye opening replies that I did not completely think through).

Example
ThreadA
    atach(SharedObject);  //Shared object passed by value, count incremented etc etc.

ThreadB
    //Accepts the object, adds it to a list of shared objects.  ThreadB is on a timer that notifies all SharedObjects of an event. Before Notifying, a copy of the list is made protected by a critical section.  The CS is released, the copies are notified.

ThreadA
    detach(SharedObject);  //Removes the shared object from the list of objects

Now, concurrently ThreadB is singaling the SharedOjbect and already made a copy of the list before ThreadA detached said shared object.  Everything is ok no?

Comment: Why a 64 bit refcount? Are you sure you aren't over-engineering this?

Comment: You could take a look at [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) if you just want to protect the counter, or [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) if you want broader protection.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it should be safe.

Why? Because in order to copy an object, the source needs to have a "reference", so it's not going away during the copy. Also, nobody is accessing an object that's currently under construction.

Destructor is safe too, since there are no references left anyway.

You may want to reconsider copying the reference count, though. Those references don't actually exist; everyone with a reference to the original would somehow have to decrease the refcount for the copy too, provided it got the original reference before the copy was made. Copies should start like new objects, with a refcount of 1.

EDIT: likewise, if you're implementing an assignment operator (which is like a copy into an existing object), the refcount of the destination object should be left as it is.

Comment: You aren't right, nothing prevent another thread to delete global object between initialization list and ctor body execution.

Comment: @Rost: That would be a different bug unrelated to this code. This code is safe so long as unrelated code doesn't have unrelated bugs. If you pass a reference to an object to another function, it's your responsibility to ensure the object exists until that function returns. (Otherwise, no member function would ever be thread safe, since the object could be destroyed during the execution of that function, which is UB.) His code doesn't have to fix bugs in its callers, nor can it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not in terms of thread safety. And this is not a bug, it's expecting behavior - otherwise there is no need to use atomics.

Comment: @Rost: Atomics are needed because another thread might increment or decrement the reference count while this function is incrementing it. It can't drop it to zero though because the caller holds a reference.

Comment: I agree with Rost, this is not safe. References are magic things that prevent something from being deleted. Even in a single threaded application, it is quite easy to have a reference to something that no longer exists. Undefined behavior, of course, but easy to invoke. If the magic doesn't work in a single threaded application, what makes you think it suddenly works in a multi-threaded application?

Comment: @DavidHammen: It is not the responsibility of a function that takes a reference to ensure its caller invokes it sensibly. *Every* function that takes a reference has a requirement that the caller ensure the object not be destroyed during the execution of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is not safe, because initialization list is not atomic (I didn't find any references to this in Standard, but it will be hardly to implement anyway).

So if another thread will delete object that is currently copied by current thread - right between initialization list execution and `InterlockedIncrement()` execution - you will receive broken (already deleted `m_data`) `m_data` and `m_count`. This will lead at least to double deletion of `m_data`.

Placing `InterlockedIncrement` to initializer list would not help because thread switching can occur after ctor call but before `m_count` initialization.

I'm not sure it is possible to make it thread safe without external lock (mutex or critical section). You could at least check counter in ctor and throw exception/create "invalid" object if it is zero, but this is not good design, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Another thread can't delete the object since this thread holds a reference to it. Whatever function called this function is calling a member function on this object, thus it must hold a reference to it. It's the caller's responsibility to ensure the object stays in existence while it's operating on an object. By this logic, no member function is ever safe since the object could always be destroyed during the execution of that member function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Exactly. No function is safe if several threads have access to object and could delete it. Reference to object has no matter it this case, it's just a pointer passed by stack.

Comment: No. A function is safe even if several threads have access to the object and can delete it because it's not the function's responsibility to prevent that. If the callers allow that, the callers are unsafe. If we accepted your logic, no functions would be safe, in which case there's no reason to criticize his code for being unsafe, since all code *must* be unsafe. Even a global lock wouldn't help, since some other thread could come along and delete the lock just as it goes to acquire that lock.

Comment: Right: if the source object is in a different thread from this constructor, there's a short window after this constructor has copied the pointer value and before it increments the reference count when a thread switch could lead to the destructor for the source object decrementing the reference count to 0 and destroying the managed object.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's an argument that applies equally well to *any* member function of *any* object. Of course, every member function of every object (and every function that takes a reference to an object) is unsafe if the underlying objects are deleted in another thread during the execution of that function. It's the caller's responsibility to make sure that doesn't happen by holding a valid reference to the underlying objects during the execution of the function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - maybe, in general. But when you're writing a wrapper class whose purpose is to **avoid** that sort of problem, you can't assume that that sort of problem won't occur. "This is thread-safe unless you screw up" is the same as "this is not thread-safe."

Comment: @PeteBecker: I cannot possibly see how that applies in this case. The function takes a reference, as all copy constructors must. Are you saying no copy constructor can be thread safe?

Comment: +1, not safe. Just because the `if` test is atomic does not make the entire `if` block atomic. It's the programmer, not C++, that needs to make the entire block atomic.

Comment: @DavidHammen: The if block doesn't need to be atomic. It just needs the operation to return true in one and only one thread after every thread is finished using the object protected by the count.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - copy constructors in general **are not thread-safe**, precisely because when the object being copied is in a thread that's different from the thread where the copy is being made, the source object can be destroyed before the copy construction is finished. In general, the solution to that problem is "don't do that". But when the purpose of the class is to ensure thread safety, "don't do that" means it has failed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, that's the reason why multithreaded programming is so complex. See e.g. `boost::shared_ptr` [thread safety requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety). It clearly states that assignment operator is not thread safe. It looks very similar to this case.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The source object cannot be destroyed before the constructor is finished because the calling function, which is clearly the same thread, holds a reference to it. Otherwise, it could not have invoked the copy constructor. Rost: Your link says "shared_ptr objects offer the same level of thread safety as built-in types" and I can't find the section you're referring to, but I suspect you're misunderstanding it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz See example 3 from link above: 

//--- Example 3 --- 
// thread A 
p = p3; // reads p3, writes p 
// thread B 
p3.reset(); // writes p3; **undefined, simultaneous read/write**

Comment: @Rost: That is a case where two threads have the *same* reference. That has no relevance to this code and wouldn't apply if each thread had its own reference, even to the same underlying object. Of course you can't share a reference across distinct code paths. The whole point of references is so that each code path can have its own to share an underlying object. If you could just share the object directly, you wouldn't need references. (And that has nothing to do with atomicity or any of the issues this question is about.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This doesn't make sense. This case is when one thread copies object owned by second thread - exactly the same case as we have in question. Example 3 is absolutely the same case, it's just about assignment, not copy ctor. And why I can't share references (whatever you mean by that)? There is nothing to prevent that if referenced object is part of shared state.

Comment: @Rost: A thread can't do anything to an object it doesn't hold a reference to. So long as something holds a reference to an object, that object cannot go away. It really is that simple. For example 3 to apply, two threads would have to be operating not just on the same object but through the same reference. In that example, `p3` is a shared pointer, which is a reference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz C++ has no built-in machinery to enforce that, you must take care of that and do it manually using some thread syncronization. So using C++ references is not thread safe. So - returning to the topic - proposed code is not thread safe.

Comment: @Rost: Is the C++ STL's `string` class thread safe? It has precisely the same requirements and guarantees. Most importantly, this code makes the underlying objects lifetimes strongly thread-safe.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, generally it's not. You cannot put it into shared state and do whatever you want without synchronization. The same thing with any built-in type - `int`, `double` etc. __Some__ operations on them are thread safe, but others are not, so generally they aren't thread safe.

Comment: @Rost: Maybe we disagree over what "thread safe" means. But if you want to argue that nothing is thread safe, not even integers, then it isn't useful to describe something as not being thread safe. I agree that in a sense, anything can be misused by threads and therefore in a sense isn't thread safe, but that's not a useful sense. And it's especially useless to describe some specific chunk of code as "not thread safe".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I believe you're misunderstanding thread safety concept. Any specific chunk of code is thread safe if it uses only objects in non-shared areas - stack, TLS, thread specific heap (or is using thread synchronization). E.g. if we change discussed ctor signature to pass `rhs` by value: `MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject rhs)` - then this ctor *becomes* thread safe. Well, it's quite useless and not a "real world" example, but just to illustrate concept.

Answer (score 0):

This code is safe so long as the calling code ensures that the object passed by reference is not destroyed during the execution of this function. This is the same for any function that takes a reference and you would have to work very hard to not do this.

The destructor is safe because the atomic decrement is guaranteed to be zero in one and only one thread. And if it is, it must be that every other thread has already finished using the object and already invoked its own decrement operation.

This assumes your interlocked operations all have full barriers.

> how could I get into a scenario where thread1 is copying and thread2 is destroying concurrently when the count == 1. There has to be a handshake between the threads, meaning thread1 has to copy the object entirely before thread2's object goes out of scope correct?

You can't, so long as each thread has its own reference to the object. The object can't be destroyed while thread1 is copying so long as thread1 has its own reference to the object. Thread1 needn't copy before thread2's reference goes away because you would never, ever touch an object unless you had a reference to it.

Individual references have weak thread safety and shouldn't be accessed in different threads concurrently. If two threads want to access the same object, they should each have their own reference. When giving a reference to an object to some other code (potentially in another thread), follow this sequence of operations:

1. Have your own reference.
2. Create the reference for the other code from your own reference.
3. Now you may destroy your reference or give away the other reference.

Comment: If I've passed a reference to an `Object` into another thread, how long do I have to keep the original object around in order to ensure that it is not destroyed during construction of a copy in the other thread?

Comment: @PeteBecker: The code that creates the other thread's reference may destroy its own reference as soon as it has completed creating the new reference. 1) Have reference. 2) Create reference for other thread. 3) Destroy own reference.

Comment: @PeteBecker: There's really only one rule: *It is the responsibility of any code that operates on an object to ensure it holds a reference to that object so long as it is operating on that object.* To pass a reference, you must create a reference to pass, which is an operation on the object. So you must hold a reference until you are finished creating the reference you will give to the other thread.

Answer (score -1):

Your copy constructor is not safe, and cannot be made safe.

But you can use your class safely if you never use new/delete, but only work with objects created and destroyed automatically (by scope).

Comment: An explanation would be helpful.